# Joining two columns into one column from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have two sql queries

```
select Course 
from StudentDB.dbo.Student 
where RollNo = 130
```

and

```
select Course 
from StudentDB.dbo.Courses 
where Course is not null
```

First query will return the following value

```
MSc
```

and the second query will return

```
MCA
MSc
CSE
ECE
EEE
```

I need to join these queries and want an output like this

```
MSc
MCA
CSE
ECE
EEE
```

That is appending the result of second query to the first query and removing the duplicate value.

**Please note** I need result of first query on the top of the result. Here Msc is the first value because it is the result of first query. I tried union. But it returns the result of the second query itself. So union of those queries won't helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a fan of DISTINCT; working from JW's answer, this will give you the distinct list of values ordered with values from StudentDB.dbo.Student first:

```
SELECT Course
FROM
(
    select Course, 1 ord from StudentDB.dbo.Student where RollNo = 130
    UNION
    select Course, 2 ord from StudentDB.dbo.Courses where Course is not null
) s
GROUP BY Course
ORDER BY min(ord)
```

Comment: Your answer is also perfect @MatthewC.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the default collation in your server is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS which means it is Case Insensitive (CI).

This makes your Msc be the same as MSC.
You need to change your collation to a different one which is not case insensitive.

See possible collations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

See usages of COLLATE
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/

Answer (score 0):

Just run this script in SQL server you will get the result, you may use it in store procedure also.

```
SELECT Course,1 ord INTO #tmpTable FROM Student

INSERT #tmpTable
SELECT Course,2 ord FROM Courses WHERE Course IS NOT NULL 
AND Course NOT IN(SELECT Course FROM Student)

SELECT Course FROM #tmpTable ORDER BY ord

DROP TABLE #tmpTable
```